# There is no data in the csv file after webscraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is the code i'm using

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0'
}

leagues = ['L1', 'GB1', 'IT1', 'FR1', 'ES1']


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        links = []
        for lea in leagues:
            print(f"Fetching Links from {lea}")
            r = req.get(url.format(lea), headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
            link = [f"{url[:31]}{item.next_element.get('href')}" for item in soup.findAll(
                "td", class_="hauptlink no-border-links hide-for-small hide-for-pad")]
            links.extend(link)

        print(f"Collected {len(links)} Links")
        goals = []
        for num, link in enumerate(links):
            print(f"Extracting Page# {num +1}")
            r = req.get(link, headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
            target = soup.find("table", class_="items")
            pn = [pn.text for pn in target.select("div.rn_nummer")]
            pos = [pos.text for pos in target.findAll("td", class_=False)]
            name = [name.text for name in target.select("td.hide")]
            dob = [date.find_next(
                "td").text for date in target.select("td.hide")]
            nat = [" / ".join([a.get("alt") for a in nat.find_all_next("td")[1] if a.get("alt")]) for nat in target.findAll(
                "td", itemprop="athlete")]
            val = [val.get_text(strip=True)
                   for val in target.select('td.rechts.hauptlink')]
            goal = zip(pn, pos, name, dob, nat, val)
            df = pd.DataFrame(goal, columns=[
                              'position_number', 'position_description', 'name', 'dob', 'nationality', 'value'])
            goals.append(df)

        new = pd.concat(goals)
        new.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)


main("https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/jumplist/startseite/wettbewerb/{}/plus/?saison_id=2019")
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? E.g. Have you inserted some print statements to check values are as expected at different points? Narrow down where the problem occurs then focus on the why.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is some of your lists are empty, so your zip object is empty and creates an empty dataframe. That has to do with the fact you aren't calling on the right direct tags (Ie. name is under a `<span>` tag, not `<td>`

Give this a try:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0'
}

leagues = ['L1', 'GB1', 'IT1', 'FR1', 'ES1']


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        links = []
        for lea in leagues:
            print(f"Fetching Links from {lea}")
            r = req.get(url.format(lea), headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
            link = [f"{url[:31]}{item.next_element.get('href')}" for item in soup.findAll(
                "td", class_="hauptlink no-border-links hide-for-small hide-for-pad")]
            links.extend(link)
    
        print(f"Collected {len(links)} Links")
        goals = []
        for num, link in enumerate(links):
            print(f"Extracting Page# {num +1}")
            r = req.get(link, headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
            target = soup.find("table", class_="items")
            
            # Get all the rows in the table
            rows = target.find_all('tr')
            
            # This particular site the data we want is in every 3rd row
            # This will essentially skip the header column <th>, and skip every 2nd and 3rd row for each player
            for row_num, row in enumerate(rows):
                if row.find('th') == None and row_num%3==1:
                    pn = row.find('div',{'class':'rn_nummer'}).text
                    pos = row.find('td', {'class':False}).text
                    
                    # Find the <span> tag that has "hide" within its class attributes
                    name = row.find('span',{'class':re.compile('.*hide.*')}).text
                    
                    # If the name not found there, we'll look in the <a> tag
                    if name == '':
                        name = row.find('a',{'class':re.compile('.*profil_tooltip.*')}).text
                    
                    # Finds the <span> tag with class attribute, then grab the next <td> tag
                    dob = row.find('span',{'class':re.compile('.*hide.*')}).find_next('td',{'class':'zentriert'}).text
                    
                    # Pull out the number betwen the (  )
                    dob_num = dob[dob.find("(")+1:dob.find(")")]
                    
                    # Finds the <span> tag with class attribute, then grab the next <td> tag, to get the <img> tag that contains the nationality in the title attribute
                    nat = row.find('span',{'class':re.compile('.*hide.*')}).find_next('td',{'class':'zentriert'}).find_next('img')['title']
                    val = row.find('td',{'class':'rechts hauptlink'}).text
                else:
                    continue
                
                # Places a dictionary of {column_names:vales} in to a list
                goals.append({'position_number':pn, 
                              'position_description':pos, 
                              'name':name, 
                              'dob':dob, 
                              'nationality':nat,
                              'value':val,
                              'dob_num':dob_num})
                    
            
        # Create dataframe from the list of rows (the list of dictionaries of {column names:values:})
        new = pd.DataFrame(goals)
        
        #Write to file
        new.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Cool. If it works for you, then kindly accept the solution.

Comment: There are some missing values of player names though. How should I tackle that ?

Comment: Give me an example of 1 and I’ll look into it

Comment: Is it the name missing? Or the value?